# docker: Error response from daemon: Container command './run' could not be invoked

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I tried to use this Dockerfile (https://gist.github.com/audy/26748bdf6f5e260dd6f6) in the following way `docker run -d --net=host --privileged=true -v /mnt/data:/export sort`, but received `docker: Error response from daemon: Container command './run' could not be invoked..`

However, the `Dockerfile` and the `run` script are both in the same folder and when I built the container `run` was added successfully to the container:

```
Step 15 : ADD ./run .
 ---> f6972313a004
Removing intermediate container 24d92f7e81df
Step 16 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Running in ee6f9345a3c5
 ---> 6dc9d4ca0d61
Removing intermediate container ee6f9345a3c5
Step 17 : ENTRYPOINT ./run
 ---> Running in a3243dae9c82
 ---> 2bde541f1c91
Removing intermediate container a3243dae9c82
Successfully built 2bde541f1c91
```

What did I do wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Mic

Answer (score 0):

Typically this kind of errors are due to file format issues with the script, for example when the script has `fileformat=dos` and it is tried to run on Linux system (the one running in the docker container) there are `^M` characters in it. This is especially likely if you are working on a Windows host.

So, check whether `run` file has set `Unix/Linux` as Line Ending and also that has execution permissions.